# Working with Hive Complex Datatypes

Tags: sql, arrays, hadoop, hive, custom-data-type

I am trying to load text file into hive db, values in the text file are `,` separated, and out of these these values one value is array type.

Here is my sample data.

```
101,suresh,67,45,67,21,hyderabad
```

here:

`101`: student roll number

`suresh` : student name

`67,45,67,21`: student marks

`hyderabad` : student location

here how I need to load into hive as

```
101,suresh,[67,45,67,21],hyderabad
```

where marks field has to loaded as array type.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **regex serde** and create text table.

The issue is with **array type** as **regex serde** doesn't allow array data type.

```
hive> CREATE TABLE details(
  id STRING,
  name STRING,
  marks STRING,
  location STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES  (
"input.regex" = "^(.*?),(.*?),(.*),(.*)"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

hive> select * from details;
+------+---------+--------------+------------+--+
|  id  |  name   |    marks     |  location  |
+------+---------+--------------+------------+--+
| 101  | suresh  | 67,45,67,21  | hyderabad  |
+------+---------+--------------+------------+--+
```

To workaround this issue you can create **another table with `array<string>`** datatype and then insert into final_table select from **regex serde table**.

```
hive> select id,name,array(marks)marks,location from access_log;
+------+---------+------------------+------------+--+
|  id  |  name   |      marks       |  location  |
+------+---------+------------------+------------+--+
| 101  | suresh  | ["67,45,67,21"]  | hyderabad  |
+------+---------+------------------+------------+--+
```

**(or)**

Instead of creating regex serde table Just create **text table with comma delimiter**

```
hive> CREATE TABLE details(
      id STRING,
      name STRING,
      marks1 STRING,
      marks2 STRING,
      marks3 STRING,
      marks4 STRING,
      location STRING
    )
    ROW FORMAT delimited Fields Terminated by ','
    STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Then create **final table with array datatype** and insert into **final_Table** select from the text table.

```
hive> select id,name,array(marks1,marks2,marks3,marks4) marks,location from details
```